# Cordova + Xcode8 = Linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode, cordova

Everything was working fine until I updated the iPad and now I can't build/install my app any more. I get the error message:

```
ld : framework not found Pods_myproject
clang: error: linker command failed with exist code 1
```

I tried to add/remove ios platform, clean ios both in cordova and xcode, remove pods folder and files, did a pod deintegrate, redid pod init and pod install, quit xcode, nothing works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check your Xcode project, you probably link to "Pods_myproject" somewhere.

1. Open Xcode
2. Click on your project
3. See the 'General' tab.
4. Remove `Pods_myproject` from **Linked Frameworks and Libraries** and **Embedded Binaries**
5. If still not resolved, search for `Pods_myproject` on the top right.

Comment: Thank you!! I have wasted so much time on this!! (I hate you Apple)